# Integration over wave number

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I came across an integral of this form in a paper:
$$
g_j\int\frac{m_{jp}(k,\omega)}{-i\omega+k^2}d\mathbf{k}d\omega,
$$
where the second-rank tensor $m_{jp}(k,\omega)$ is proportional to:
$$
m_{jp}(k,\omega)\propto\delta_{jp}-k_jk_p/k^2.
$$
The result should be an integral of the form:
$$
\mathbf{g}\int_0^{\infty}f(k,\omega)dkd\omega.
$$
The whole derivation is rather complicated and there aren't a lot of explanations. I can't figure out how the integral over $\mathbf{k}$ is turned into one for $k$ and the $\delta_{jp}$ and $k_j$, $k_p$ terms are delt with. The function $f$ is a complicated function of logarithms and arctangents, so I assume the step involves quite a bit of math.

Comment: I assume $g$ is a constant vector?

Comment: Also what are the integration domains for $\boldsymbol k $ and $\omega$? Are they $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R$ respectively?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{g}$ is constant over $k$ and $\omega$. The integration domains are $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R}$ for $\mathbf{k}$, $k$, and $\omega$, respectively. At least I assume so. It was not specified in the paper, as is usually not the case in physics (to my knowledge at least).

Comment: Can you give a link to the paper?

Comment: Here: https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1992A%26A...260..494K

Comment: I want to get eq. 3.2 from the second term of eq. 2.5 and eqs 2.19, 2.15 and 2.9

Comment: This is going to be quite a task - allow me some time to get back to you.

Comment: No worries, thanks a lot! By the way, I suspect there is a mistake somewhere along the way, hence why I am trying to reproduce the equation. Using eqs. 4.1 and 4.2 in eq 3.6, I find that it blows up for small $\beta$, which should not happen.

Comment: Yikes. It's quite a complicated paper. As best as I can tell, $G^j m_{ij}=G^j\delta_{ij}-G^jk_ik_j|k|^{-2}$, so the first term there reduces to just $G^i$. As for the second term, I think it is dealt with in another integral. I don't think the second term of equation 2.5 and equation 3.2 are actually equal.

Comment: Haha indeed! Yeah, it's that second term that bothers me especially, and how they get all these logs and arctans to pop up. And you are right, they are not really equal. Essentially, $\mathcal{E}=(\mathbf{U}_{\text{dia}}+\mathbf{U}_{\text{dens}})\times\mathbf{B}$, $\mathcal{E}$ is given by eq. 2.5, and $\mathbf{U}_{\text{dens}}$ by eq. 3.2. But I'm now noticing that something doesn't quite work. In eq. 2.5, the integral is over $d\mathbf{k}$, a vector, while taking into account the sums, we have the $f$ index remaining. So the RHS is a second-rank tensor, but the LHS is a vector. Confusing...